# Using a copper wire as a heater

Tags: heat

I would like to create a food heater , the heater should reach around 80C. I had an idea of using a copper wire (or any other metal / alloy) , connecting it to a power source , and thus heating the wire.

What i want to ask is first of all is it possible and do you think the wire will heat , and how much voltage will i need to heat the wire ? . Second question is can i safely cook food using that wire , and eating that food afterward ?.

Comment: This is far too broad and it is not clear what you are asking. Most of the issues are on the food safety axis and are probably not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Can you safely build this (without burning your home down) is my question to you.

Comment: @Andyaka - I think that, considering the OP is apparently unaware that appliances like toasters already exist, the answer to your question is "probably not"...

Comment: An electric range. That's what to u are trying to recreate. An electric stove top.

Comment: Also copper is a poor choice for this.

Comment: This is a Thermodynamics 201 question. How much energy is need to raise mass of X by 60'C.  What heating rate is needed? What is the thermal resistance? makes estimates.  I expect 250W range which you can calc from wire resistance. it should be stainless food grade wire if exposed inside. normally it is Nichrome or insulated magnet wire on outside then insulated with air then enclosed.

Comment: Nobody has even mentioned yet that you'd effectively be shorting out your power supply, with the current only limited by the resistance of the wire itself. Your supply would need to be able to safely supply lots of amps

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using the cooker in your kitchen - e.g. is this meant to be a portable device?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. You probably shouldn't, though.

This is the operating principle behind essentially every appliance that heats; put a current through a wire and it gets hot.

For a food heater, because of the generally high powers required, I would *highly* recommend you use an off-the-shelf waterproof heater. This will be much safer then making one yourself.

If you really need to do this, I would highly, highly recommend you not use wall AC power for this, because the electrocution and fire hazard is very high. I would recommend using a low-voltage (12v, say) supply, to keep things safer.

The amount of voltage one needs depends on how many watts of heating power you want.

Typically, because of the low resistance of copper, you use high-resistance Nichrome or Kanthal wire. Copper itself isn't typically used.

Comment: Just came across this old thread while reading up on heating elements. Heating elements in CPAP hoses are copper wires. They indeed operate off 12V, as you said, and that quite low-power, just to maintain the wall temperature of the hose above dew point to prevent condensation (surely would not work as a food heater).